# How to post on Facebook page as Page Post from app via graph API in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on Facebook page as a page post. I using am below graph code API, but post coming on side as other people post, not as page admin/Page itself:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Testing Post", @"name",
                             @"This is testing", @"message",
                             @"this is description", @"description",                            
                             nil];  

 NSString *feed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Page ID/feed"];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:feed
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              if(!error){

                                  NSLog(@"%@", result);
                              }
                              else{
                                  NSLog(@"Error %@", error);

                                  }

                          }];
```

Comment: Is your session opened?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post as the Page itself, you'll need to use a Page Access Token with the `publish_pages` permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 1):

**Here is Complete Answer**

```
NSString *accesstoken = <Page_Access_Token>

  NSDictionary*  params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Post heading", @"name",
              accesstoken, @"access_token",
              @"Type post message", @"message",
              @"Hyperlink to your post", @"link",
              @"Add description", @"description",
              @"Image url string", @"picture",
              nil];

    FBRequest *requestToPost = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:nil
                                                        graphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                                       parameters:params
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"];    

    FBRequestConnection *requestToPostConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [requestToPostConnection addRequest:requestToPost completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {             
             NSLog(@" %@", result);             
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", error);                        
         } 

     }];
```

Comment: Please make sure your Facebook app ID have manage_pages and publish_pages in Status and Reviews. First get your page token, and then use above code to share. Ask me anything if you have any issue.